# Change text in DIV on click with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button with text in it. When clicking this button it will be disabled (not clickable) after 3 clicks. Also the button text must changes at each click.

See my example (press render to see it work):
http://jsbin.com/univu3/edit#source

Now I want this same functionality but then with a DIV. This is my javascript code I have cooked up so far:

```
//Hint
function hint() {
var count = 3

if(count==0) {
        $(this).addClass('disabled');
    };
```

My div:

```
<div class="ht">HINT (3)</div>
```

So after 3 clicks the (3) must be (0) and the class "disabled" must be loaded (making the div look like it is disabled.

Any ideas how tp pull this off?

Thank you for your time

ps I use jQuery too

Comment: The disabled attribute only works for input elements.

Comment: Your example works just fine for me. What is the question exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice and short.[updated]

```
$('.ht').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var pos = parseInt($this.text().match(/\d+/g)[0]) //use regex to pull the number out;

    if(!pos) return false;

    $this.text($this.text().replace(pos, --pos))

    if(!pos){
        $this.addClass('disabled');
    }
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/brentmn/MsQMs/1/

Comment: Thanks for catching that.  I updated the answer and the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You could make something like this:

```
var count=0 
$('.ht').click(function (){    
count++;    
if (count == 1){$('.ht').html('hint 1');}    
if (count == 2) {$('.ht').html('hint 2');}    
if (count == 3) {$('.ht').html('hint 3');
$(.ht).addClass('disabled');} 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var hintcount = $('.ht span'),
    availableHint = hintcount.html() | 0;

$('.ht').on('click.threetimes', function() {
   if (availableHint--) {
       hintcount.html(availableHint);
   }
   else {
       $(this).off('click.threetimes').addClass('disabled');
   }
});



<div class="ht">HINT (<span>3</span>)</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it (no JQuery):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

</head>
<body>

<div id="div">Stop clicking me!</div>

<script>

document.getElementById("div").addEventListener("click", function listener() {

    //Get the current 'clicksSoFar' attribute on the div.
    var clicks = +this.getAttribute("clicksSoFar");

    //Add to its number of clicks.
    clicks++;

    //If it's greater or equal to 3,
    if(clicks >= 3) {

        //Gray out the div here (or something) and remove the listener

        // --- YOUR CODE HERE ---

        this.removeEventListener("click", listener, true);

    }

    //Set the clicksSoFar attribute to the new number of clicks
    this.setAttribute("clicksSoFar", clicks);


}, true);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```